# Flutter Dart - Calling sqflite function in Isolate causes error

Tags: flutter, dart-isolates

I have a sqflite database that works, unit tests work. I want to call a sqflite method in onTap method. I understand I cannot execute the sqflite function in the main UI thread (Flutter tells me that at runtime). So I created an Isolate to call the sqflite function, which gives a different error. The Isolate works if I don't call the sqflite function, works if I just return a bool. Here is the code and exception - thanks for any suggestions:

---

### Snippet from UI

```dart
    Widget loginButton(BuildContext context) {
    return Expanded(
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20.0, right: 5.0, top: 20.0, bottom: 0.0),
        child: GestureDetector(
          onTap: () {
            if (emailController.text.length > 1 && passwordController.text.length > 7) {
              /// Find user. Then...
              doCheckIfFoundUser(emailController.text.trim(), passwordController.text);
            } else {
              printUserNotFound();
            }

          },
        child: buttonContainer(Colors.indigo, "Login", 20.0),
        ),
      ),
    );
```

### Method called from UI

```dart
doCheckIfFoundUser(String email, String password) async {
    var result;
    List<String> emailPasswordList = new List();
    emailPasswordList.add(email);
    emailPasswordList.add(password);
    var receivePort = new ReceivePort();
    Isolate.spawn(callbackFunction, receivePort.sendPort);
    SendPort sendPort = await receivePort.first;
    var ans = await sendReceive(sendPort, emailPasswordList);
    setState(() {
      result = ans;
      print("The value is $result - please do your thing");
    });
}
```

### Isolate Callback

```dart
static void callbackFunction(SendPort callerSendPort) async {

    ReceivePort newIsolateReceivePort = ReceivePort();


    callerSendPort.send(newIsolateReceivePort.sendPort);
    var msg = await newIsolateReceivePort.first;
    List<String> emailPasswordList = msg[0];

    print("email: ${emailPasswordList[0]}, password: ${emailPasswordList[1]}");

    bool foundUser = await searchForUser(emailPasswordList[0], emailPasswordList[1]);
    SendPort replyPort = msg[1];
    replyPort.send(foundUser);
}
```

```dart
Future sendReceive(SendPort send, message) {
  ReceivePort receivePort = ReceivePort();
  send.send([message, receivePort.sendPort]);
  return receivePort.first;}
```

---

> I/flutter ( 2073): email: email, password: Passw0rd
>
> E/flutter ( 2073): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_isolate.cc(805)] Unhandled exception:
>
> E/flutter ( 2073): error: native function 'Window_sendPlatformMessage' (4 arguments) cannot be found
>
> E/flutter ( 2073): #0      Window.sendPlatformMessage (dart:ui/window.dart:1089:9)
>
> E/flutter ( 2073): #1      _DefaultBinaryMessenger._sendPlatformMessage (package:flutter/src/services/binary_messenger.dart:85:15)
>
> E/flutter ( 2073): #2      _DefaultBinaryMessenger.send (package:flutter/src/services/binary_messenger.dart:129:12)
>
> E/flutter ( 2073): #3      MethodChannel.invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:309:51)
>
> E/flutter ( 2073):
>
> E/flutter ( 2073): #4      invokeMethod (package:sqflite/src/sqflite_impl.dart:18:34)
>
> E/flutter ( 2073):
>
> E/flutter ( 2073): #5      SqfliteDatabaseFactoryImpl.invokeMethod (package:sqflite/src/factory_impl.dart:33:7)
>
> E/flutter ( 2073): #6      _SqfliteDatabaseFactoryImpl&Object&SqfliteDatabaseFactoryMixin.safeInvokeMethod. (package:sqflite/src/factory_mixin.dart:22:35)
>
> E/flutter ( 2073): #7      wrapDatabaseException (package:sqflite/src/exception_impl.dart:7:34)
>   E/flutter ( 2073): .
>
> E/flutter ( 2073): #8      SqfliteDatabaseFactoryImpl.wrapDatabaseException (package:sqflite/src/factory_impl.dart:29:7).
>
> E/flutter ( 2073): #9      _SqfliteDatabaseFactoryImpl&Object&SqfliteDatabaseFactoryMixin.safeInvokeMethod (package:sqflite/src/factory_mixin.dart:22:7). 
>   E/flutter ( 2073): #10     _SqfliteDatabaseFactoryImpl&Object&SqfliteDatabaseFactoryMixin.getDatabasesPath (package:sqflite/src/factory_mixin.dart:136:17). 
>   E/flutter ( 2073): 
>   E/flutter ( 2073): #11     getDatabasesPath.  (package:sqflite/sqflite.dart:166:54)
>   E/flutter ( 2073): #12     UsersSqflite.init (package:himrepo/controller/users_database.dart:20:47). 
>   E/flutter ( 2073): . 
>   E/flutter ( 2073): #13     _LoginPageState.searchForUser.  (package:himrepo/ui/login.dart:268:24). 
>   E/flutter ( 2073): . 
>   E/flutter ( 2073): #14     _LoginPageState.callbackFunction(package:himrepo/ui/login.dart:166:28). 
>   E/flutter ( 2073): . 
>   E/flutter ( 2073): #15     _startIsolate..  (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:304:17). 
>   E/flutter ( 2073): #16     _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage(dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:172:12).

### Executing Sqflite method directly gives

```dart
E/AndroidRuntime( 6628): FATAL EXCEPTION: Sqflite
E/AndroidRuntime( 6628): java.lang.RuntimeException: Methods marked with @UiThread must be executed on the main thread. Current thread: Sqflite
E/AndroidRuntime( 6628):    at io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterJNI.ensureRunningOnMainThread(FlutterJNI.java:794)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6628):    at io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterJNI.invokePlatformMessageResponseCallback(FlutterJNI.java:727)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6628):    at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger$Reply.reply(DartMessenger.java:140)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6628):    at io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel$IncomingMethodCallHandler$1.success(MethodChannel.java:225)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6628):    at com.tekartik.sqflite.SqflitePlugin$6.run(SqflitePlugin.java:778)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6628):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6628):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6628):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6628):    at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:65)
```

Comment: `"I understand I cannot execute the sqflite function in the main UI thread"` - there is nothing wrong in executing sqflite in the main UI thread - they are async methods that do not block the main UI thread

Comment: If I call the method in onTap I get: java.lang.RuntimeException: Methods marked with @UiThread must be executed on the main thread. Current thread: Sqflite

Comment: what method is marked with @UiThread?

Comment: I can't find it. It's not any of my methods. I searched through sqflite source.

Comment: I assume it's at com.tekartik.sqflite.SqflitePlugin$6.run(SqflitePlugin.java:778). I pasted exception to main post.

Comment: go to `sqflite` installation folder and run the example code located in `example` subfolder

Comment: I'll try it and post my results soon.

Comment: I was able to recreate it using simple openDatabase at https://pub.dev/packages/sqflite#-readme-tab-

Comment: dont get it: so does the example app work? if not, post the full stacktrace you see

Comment: I did post the full stacktrace, see "Executing Sqflite method directly gives" in main post above.

Comment: is it a stacktrace when you run [example](https://github.com/tekartik/sqflite/tree/master/sqflite/example) app? without any modifications?

Comment: I did not run the full example, I'll try the full example now.

Comment: I ran the example and it worked. I compared my pubspec.yaml and the example's pubspec.yaml. I had some suspicious plugins in mine (json_annotation, json_serializable) so I removed them and my app now works. Perhaps the annotations were getting confused. Anyway, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @pskink for helping. The Isolate works, but I was getting exceptions when running sqflite from a Widget onTap event. It turned out that a plugin (json_annotation) I included in my pubspec.yaml was somehow contributing to the exception: "Methods marked with @UiThread must be executed on the main thread. Current thread: Sqflite". After removing that plugin the app works.

Answer (score 0):

In short - your answer is `Drift` SQL library.

Use [Drift](https://pub.dev/packages/drift) library for your Flutter Dart application. It is the only major persistence library with builtin threading support, allowing you to run database code across isolates with zero additional effort.